# How to copy list into string in python?

Tags: python, string, list

list = ['london', 'paris', 'beijing']

I would like convert to a string that contains same as list.

Example:
str = "['london', 'paris', 'beijing]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = ['london', 'paris', 'beijing']
s = str(l)
print(s) # ouput: ['london', 'paris', 'beijing']
```

Comment: I have error : TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: It's because you named your string variable `str` like the built in function. Try changing it to `s` or `string` like I have in the answer

Comment: >>> l = ['london', 'paris', 'beijing'] 
>>> s = str(l)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: did you restart the shell first?

Comment: It's working after restart. Thank you so much.